# I'm getting error "django.db.utils.OperationalError: no such function: JSON_VALID"

Tags: json, python-3.x, sqlite

When I'm trying to launch tests by the command `python3 manage.py test --settings=apps.settings_test`, I'm getting an error:

> django.db.utils.OperationalError: no such function: JSON_VALID

My environment:

- SQLite 3 - 3.36.0
- Python 3 - 3.9.9

#### File *settings_test.py*

```
from .settings import *

DATABASES['default'] = {
    'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
    'NAME': ':memory:'
}
```

As I understood my SQLite 3 version doesn't support JsonField(). However, my colleague's SQLite 3 version is 3.31.1 and everything works fine.
How I can solve it?
Entire stracktrace:

```
The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ainura/Desktop/edengine-units-api/manage.py", line 22, in <module>
    main()
  File "/home/ainura/Desktop/edengine-units-api/manage.py", line 18, in main
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/home/ainura/Desktop/edengine-units-api/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 419, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/home/ainura/Desktop/edengine-units-api/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 413, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/home/ainura/Desktop/edengine-units-api/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/test.py", line 23, in run_from_argv
    super().run_from_argv(argv)
  File "/home/ainura/Desktop/edengine-units-api/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 354, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "/home/ainura/Desktop/edengine-units-api/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 398, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/home/ainura/Desktop/edengine-units-api/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/test.py", line 55, in handle
    failures = test_runner.run_tests(test_labels)
  File "/home/ainura/Desktop/edengine-units-api/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/test/runner.py", line 725, in run_tests
    old_config = self.setup_databases(aliases=databases)
  File "/home/ainura/Desktop/edengine-units-api/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/test/runner.py", line 643, in setup_databases
    return _setup_databases(
  File "/home/ainura/Desktop/edengine-units-api/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/test/utils.py", line 179, in setup_databases
    connection.creation.create_test_db(
  File "/home/ainura/Desktop/edengine-units-api/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/creation.py", line 74, in create_test_db
    call_command(
  File "/home/ainura/Desktop/edengine-units-api/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 181, in call_command
    return command.execute(*args, **defaults)
  File "/home/ainura/Desktop/edengine-units-api/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 398, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/home/ainura/Desktop/edengine-units-api/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 89, in wrapped
    res = handle_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/ainura/Desktop/edengine-units-api/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/migrate.py", line 244, in handle
    post_migrate_state = executor.migrate(
  File "/home/ainura/Desktop/edengine-units-api/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 117, in migrate
    state = self._migrate_all_forwards(state, plan, full_plan, fake=fake, fake_initial=fake_initial)
  File "/home/ainura/Desktop/edengine-units-api/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 147, in _migrate_all_forwards
    state = self.apply_migration(state, migration, fake=fake, fake_initial=fake_initial)
  File "/home/ainura/Desktop/edengine-units-api/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 227, in apply_migration
    state = migration.apply(state, schema_editor)
  File "/home/ainura/Desktop/edengine-units-api/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/migrations/migration.py", line 126, in apply
    operation.database_forwards(self.app_label, schema_editor, old_state, project_state)
  File "/home/ainura/Desktop/edengine-units-api/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/migrations/operations/models.py", line 92, in database_forwards
    schema_editor.create_model(model)
  File "/home/ainura/Desktop/edengine-units-api/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/schema.py", line 345, in create_model
    self.execute(sql, params or None)
  File "/home/ainura/Desktop/edengine-units-api/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/schema.py", line 145, in execute
    cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/home/ainura/Desktop/edengine-units-api/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 66, in execute
    return self._execute_with_wrappers(sql, params, many=False, executor=self._execute)
  File "/home/ainura/Desktop/edengine-units-api/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 75, in _execute_with_wrappers
    return executor(sql, params, many, context)
  File "/home/ainura/Desktop/edengine-units-api/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 84, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/home/ainura/Desktop/edengine-units-api/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 90, in __exit__
    raise dj_exc_value.with_traceback(traceback) from exc_value
  File "/home/ainura/Desktop/edengine-units-api/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 82, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql)
  File "/home/ainura/Desktop/edengine-units-api/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/backends/sqlite3/base.py", line 421, in execute
    return Database.Cursor.execute(self, query)
django.db.utils.OperationalError: no such function: JSON_VALID
```

Comment: post the entire stacktrace, not just a single line from it

Comment: @DeepSpace added

Comment: @DeepSpace: Yes, but it is apparently necessary to state that it should be as text, not as an image.

Comment: Please provide it as text instead of as an image (Ctrl + K should work on selected lines to format it properly). See e.g. *[Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/)*. It includes (my emphasis) *"Images should only be used to illustrate problems that* ***can't be made clear in any other way***, *such as to provide screenshots of a user interface."*

Comment: @Peter Mortensen - done